# authentication_form not working on the LoginView class in DJango

Tags: django, django-forms

I actually creating a customize authentication form in `LoginView` class but it is not working.

here is the forms.py:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs = {
                'class': 'input100',
            }),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {
                'class': 'input100',
            })
        }
```

my class view:

```
class Login(LoginView):
    authentication_form = LoginForm
    template_name = 'content/login.html'
```

here is my html template:

```
{% extends 'body/login.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-login100">
    <div class="wrap-login100 p-t-50 p-b-90">
        <form class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <span class="login100-form-title p-b-51">
                Login
            </span>

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16" data-validate = "Username is required">
                    {{ field }}
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

            <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-17">
                <button class="login100-form-btn">
                    Login
                </button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

but in the templates its still loading the default form.

Comment: can you share your HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AuthenticationForm` is not a `ModelForm` so providing a `Meta` in a subclass will not do anything. You have to override the fields to changes their properties

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        max_length=254,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'input100',
        })
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'class': 'input100',
        })
    )
```